How many TCP connections are involved during a SOCKS5 BIND request?
Let's review together RFC1928:

BIND
The BIND request is used in protocols which require the client to
accept connections from the server.  FTP is a well-known example,
which uses the primary client-to-server connection for commands and
status reports, but may use a server-to-client connection for
transferring data on demand (e.g. LS, GET, PUT).
It is expected that the client side of an application protocol will
use the BIND request only to establish secondary connections after a
primary connection is established using CONNECT.

So, for example, a first CONNECT request follows
        +-------+-------+-------+------+----------+----------+
        |  VER  |  CMD  |  RSV  | ATYP | DST.ADDR | DST.PORT |
        +-------+-------+-------+------+----------+----------+
        | X'05' | X'01' | X'00' |  1   | Variable |    2     |
        +-------+-------+-------+------+----------+----------+

In this case, DST.ADDR and DST.PORT are the address and port of the target host the SOCKS5 server must on behalf of the SOCKS5 client relay packet to ? What kind of connection is this ? A client-to-server connection ? What is the role of this connection ? To relay BIND requests that follows ?
But after that it says this:

In is expected that
a SOCKS server will use DST.ADDR and DST.PORT in evaluating the BIND
request.

Are we already in the process of a secondary connection ? It shouldn't be the DST.ADDR and DST.PORT of the CONNECT request ?
Then it says this:

Two replies are sent from the SOCKS server to the client during a
BIND operation.  The first is sent after the server creates and binds
a new socket. The BND.PORT field contains the port number that the
SOCKS server assigned to listen for an incoming connection.  The
BND.ADDR field contains the associated IP address.

So, here comes the BIND request ?
        +-------+-------+-------+------+----------+----------+
        |  VER  |  CMD  |  RSV  | ATYP | DST.ADDR | DST.PORT |
        +-------+-------+-------+------+----------+----------+
        | X'05' | X'02' | X'00' |  1   | Variable |    2     |
        +-------+-------+-------+------+----------+----------+

What is the role of DST.ADDR and DST.PORT here ?
What follows is the first Operation Reply:
        +-------+-------+-------+------+----------+----------+
        |  VER  |  REP  |  RSV  | ATYP | BND.ADDR | BND.PORT |
        +-------+-------+-------+------+----------+----------+
        | X'05' | X'00' | X'00' |  1   | Variable |    2     |
        +-------+-------+-------+------+----------+----------+

BND.ADDR and BND.PORT I assume are the address and port that the SOCKS5 server has bound for listening incoming connection ?

The client will typically use these pieces of information to notify (via the primary
or control connection) the application server of the rendezvous
address.

What is the primary or control connection ?
The connection established during the CONNECT request or the BIND request ?
And, finally, what follows what it does even mean ?

The second reply occurs only after the anticipated incoming
connection succeeds or fails.
In the second reply, the BND.PORT and BND.ADDR fields contain the
address and port number of the connecting host.

Which connection is the data connection ?
Can someone explain ?
I hope I explained myself in my limited English.
I am writing an RFC1928 compliant SOCKS5 server in Erlang but I did not understand fully the flow of a BIND request-connection.

Imagine that you want to use the proxy for FTP with active mode (see RFC 959). In this case you have one control connection (done with CONNECT) and multiple data connections, each requiring the FTP client to listen for incoming connection (done with BIND). The FTP clients needs to let the FTP server know which bind addr + port are used - that's why it needs to get these information back from the proxy.
